# Function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here create a DF

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0],
                       [3, 4, np.nan, 1],
                       [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],
                       [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 4]],
                      columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Then fill the NaN values

```
df1=df.fillna(0)
```

The DF is

```
    A   B   C   D
0   0.0 2.0 0.0 0
1   3.0 4.0 0.0 1
2   0.0 0.0 0.0 5
3   0.0 3.0 0.0 4
```

Create a function that apply an operation for each columns of the DF, I try to create only one column name 'N' that bring the max value of all columns

```
def Nuevo(data1, data2, data3,data4):
    if data1 !=0:
        return data1*5
    elif data2 !=0:
        return data1*10
    elif data3 != 0:
        return data1*7
    elif data4 != 0:
        return data1*3
```

So a call the function, creating the new column to add to DF

```
df1['N']= Nuevo(df1.A, df1.B, df1.C, df1.D)
```

I try to create a new column 'N' to aggregate to the DF, but have a error in pyhton

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-4a2cc80232d0> in <module>
----> 1 df1['N']= Nuevo(df1.A, df1.B, df1.C, df1.D)

<ipython-input-36-7a080acd6ed0> in Nuevo(data1, data2, data3, data4)
      1 def Nuevo(data1, data2, data3,data4):
----> 2     if data1 !=0:
      3         return data1*5
      4     elif data2 !=0:
      5         return data1*10

~\anaconda3\envs\IA\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1437     @final
   1438     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1439         raise ValueError(
   1440             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1441             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Can you add the expected output for the column `N` with this `df`?

Comment: Yes, the idea is create a new column N with the highest value of A to D

Comment: Search with the error message - `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`. There will plenty of questions and answers for you to read so you will understand what the error means.

Comment: You don't need the if conditions at all. You can simply multiple the row elementwise with the multipliers and take a max. You can use `Nuevo = lambda x: (x*[5,10,7,3]).max()` and apply it on the df over `axis=1` (each row). Check my answer for more details.

Answer (score 4):

**NOTE:** I am assuming your df is the dataframe where you have replaced `Nan` with `0`s.

Does this work for you?

#### With apply and an explicit function

If you want to create a separate function to apply to each row then try this -

```
### USING LAMBDA FUNCTION
Nuevo = lambda x: (x*[5,10,7,3]).max()
df['N'] = df.apply(Nuevo, axis=1)
```

```
     A    B    C  D     N
0  0.0  2.0  0.0  0  20.0
1  3.0  4.0  0.0  1  40.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  5  15.0
3  0.0  3.0  0.0  4  30.0
```

Another way of writing a lambda function is -

```
#WITHOUT LAMBDA FUNCTION
def Nuevo(x):
    return (x*[5,10,7,3]).max()

df['N'] = df.apply(Nuevo, axis=1)
```

```
     A    B    C  D     N
0  0.0  2.0  0.0  0  20.0
1  3.0  4.0  0.0  1  40.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  5  15.0
3  0.0  3.0  0.0  4  30.0
```

1. Here the function takes a series `x` and it multiples it elementwise with the list `[5,10,7,3]`. Then it takes the `max()` of that series.
2. When you apply this using `df.apply(Nuevo, axis=1)`, the function is applied row-wise, which means the `x` in this case is 1 row of data.
3. The above operation is applied on each row of data and max is returned for each row.

---

#### Without apply

```
df['N'] = (df*[5,10,7,3]).max(1)
print(df)
```

```
     A    B    C  D     N
0  0.0  2.0  0.0  0  20.0
1  3.0  4.0  0.0  1  40.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  5  15.0
3  0.0  3.0  0.0  4  30.0
```

1. `df*[5,10,7,3]` multiplies each column with the respective scalar
2. `.max(1)` takes row-wise max and that is stored in `df['N']`

Comment: This was a very insightful answer, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in how you are using the function Nuevo, when you do the operation

```
if data1 !=0:
```

Python is expecting 1 value to compare if is different from 0, but you are giving it a whole Series that has as many values as there are rows in your dataframe

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer. Just an explanation of the error.

Comment: I need apply a operation for each row for the all Series and create a new column N with de highest value of the all columns

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i am wrong i think you are trying to get maximum value of each column \

```
def multiply(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if i == 0:
            data.loc[i] = data.loc[i]*5
        elif i == 1:
            data.loc[i] = data.loc[i]*10
        elif i == 2:
            data.loc[i] = data.loc[i]*7
        elif i == 3:
            data.loc[i] = data.loc[i]*3

for i in df1.columns:
    multiply(df1[i])
```

Then you can use basic list comprehension to add max(N) columns.

```
df1["N"] =  [max(df1[i]) for i in df.columns]


      A     B    C   D     N
0   0.0  10.0  0.0   0  30.0
1  30.0  40.0  0.0  10  40.0
2   0.0   0.0  0.0  35   0.0
3   0.0   9.0  0.0  12  35.0
```

I am sure that there are many easy ways but i am a little bit sleepy :)))

Comment: Yes, but before that I need multiply each row of column